# Apply BFS, with goal node what is the path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I is the starting node and E is the goal node. What will be the path that would be return by BFS?
I know this is easy the path that I found is I-H-E but my teacher is saying that the correct path is I-F-H-C-E. So I really don't know how did she found that path. Any idea?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfDrx.png]

Comment: If there are no weight on the edges it will be I-H-E. I recommend to ask your teacher what he expects as correct answer. BFS finds the shortest path (one of them) fist and I-H-E is the only shortest one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to be off-topic, please consider the guidelines [*"What topics can I ask about here?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path would be E-H-I.

Initially visited node: I

After the first iteration visited nodes [ I, F, H ]

Second Iteration visited nodes [ I, F, H, E, G, C ]

Also, the path leading to E, in this case, is though H. So I -> H -> E.